# Bug where rendered images derived randomly from enum constantly change colors when launched

Tags: java, random, enums, libgdx, render

I'm trying to make an android app that is similar to the concept of candy crush. But I'm currently stuck at a bug that endlessly changes the colors of the blocks when I render them and launch the application.

Here's the code so far...

EnumColors class for determining color of blocks:

```
public class EnumColors {

    FileHandle filehandle;
    Color color;
    enum Color { RED, BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW, PURPLE,;

    private static final List<Color> VALUES =
            Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values()));
          private static final int SIZE = VALUES.size();
          private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

          public static Color randomColor()  {
            return VALUES.get(RANDOM.nextInt(SIZE));
          }
    }

    public EnumColors () {

        color = EnumColors.Color.randomColor();

    }

    public FileHandle determineColor() {

        switch (color) {
        case RED:
            filehandle = Gdx.files.internal("redblock.png");
            break;

        case BLUE:
            filehandle = Gdx.files.internal("blueblock.png");
            break;

        case GREEN:
            filehandle = Gdx.files.internal("greenblock.png");
            break;

        case PURPLE:
            filehandle = Gdx.files.internal("purpleblock.png");
            break;

        case YELLOW:
            filehandle = Gdx.files.internal("yellowblock.png");
            break;

        }
        return filehandle;
    }
}
```

Blocks class for creating the blocks:

```
public class Blocks extends EnumColors {

    Texture texture;
    EnumColors enumcolors;

    public Blocks() {

    enumcolors = new EnumColors();
    texture = new Texture(enumcolors.determineColor());


    }
}
```

PracticeMode class that will be launched and will render the blocks:

```
public class PracticeMode extends ApplicationAdapter{

    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture texture;

    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }


    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.09f, 0.28f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Blocks block = new Blocks();

        for(int i = 0, x = 100; i < 36; i++, x += 50){
            batch.begin();
            block = new Blocks();
            if(i < 6){
                batch.draw(texture = block.texture, x, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15);
            }
            block = new Blocks();
            if(i > 5 && i < 12){
                if(x == 400){
                    x = 100;
                }
                batch.draw(texture = block.texture, x, 40, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15);
            }
            block = new Blocks();
            if(i > 11 && i < 18){
                if(x == 400){
                    x = 100;
                }
                batch.draw(texture = block.texture, x, 80, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15);
            }
            block = new Blocks();
            if(i > 17 && i < 24){
                if(x == 400){
                    x = 100;
                }
                batch.draw(texture = block.texture, x, 120, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15);
            }
            block = new Blocks();
            if(i > 23 && i < 30){
                if(x == 400){
                    x = 100;
                }
                batch.draw(texture = block.texture, x, 160, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15);
            }
            block = new Blocks();
            if(i > 29 && i < 36){
                if(x == 400){
                    x = 100;
                }
                batch.draw(texture = block.texture, x, 200, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/15);
            }
            batch.end();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why so many calls to `block = new Blocks();`?

Comment: That's true. I was just testing so many different combinations, I will change that, thanks

Comment: `color.toString().toLowerCase() + "block.png"` if you use that you can get rid of the switch statement

Comment: Thanks Harry that worked perfectly but the bug still seems to be there unfortunately